# How to manually assign UUID to Openstack machine images created through Packer?

Tags: jenkins, virtual-machine, openstack, uuid, packer

I'm working with **Packers** for creating **Openstack** **Machine Images** via a Jenkins pipeline and my current requirement is to assign, **custom UUID's** to created machine images. I'm aware that image creation APIs auto assign an unique UUID to created images during build process, but I want to override it and assign my **custom defined UUID** to those images. Is there any way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it's not supported by Packer. You can probably do some tricks with the manifest post-processor and the shell-local post-processor to copy the image with the cli to a certain id.